# Encryption algorithm from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, android, c++, xamarin

My company has a server running on C++. I'm making a mobile app using Xamarin (C#).
The server has a simple criptografy for a socket communication and the messages are sent as strings.

This is the C++ algorythm (QT):

```
    void Cripto::criptog(QString key, unsigned char *text) {
        int i = 0, y = 0, o = 0;
        int blockSize = 3;
        int len = strlen((char*)text);

        for(i = 0, y = 0; i < len;) {
            for(o = 0; o <= blockSize; o++) {
                if(i >= len) break;
                if(text[i] != 0) {
                    if(y >= key.length()) y = 0;
                    text[i] = text[i] ^ key.at(y).toAscii();
                }
                i++;
            }
            y++;
            if(y >= key.length()) {
                y = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my "translation":

```
public static string cripto(byte[] mtext) {
        int i = 0, y = 0, o = 0;
        int blockSize = 3;
        int len = mtext.Length;
        byte[] text = mtext;
        string mkey = "!%&@!*$";
        byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mkey);


        for(i = 0, y = 0; i < len;) {
            for(o = 0; o <= blockSize; o++) {
                if(i >= len) {
                    break;
                }
                if(text[i] != 0) {
                    if(y >= key.Length) { 
                        y = 0;
                    }
                    text[i] = (byte)((text[i]) ^ (key[y]));
                }
                i++;
            }
            y++;
            if(y >= key.Length) {
                y = 0;
            }
        }
        return(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(text));
        }
```

When I receive somthing from the server, I can only understand parts of the message, like somehow the encoding is wrong or something like that.
Here's an example of a "messy" answer:

```
10;50;230.1_2.1X6.1?7;5>30;0013?PASPE OFCRA"HA +  NA LELTOR?
```

That last part (?PASPE OFCRA"HA +  NA LELTOR?) is "readable", since the protocol is written in portuguese. The correct would be: "PASSE O CRACHA NA LEITORA"... I guess...

Is there anything wrong with my C# code?

The C++ uses the unsigned char. After searching a while, I found that the C# equivalent of that is simply a byte. Am I right?

Comment: The system must use the ASCII encoding.

Comment: Whats the input (the encrypted message)?

Comment: I just compared the both algorithms with some dummy data. The output is the same. So I think it has something to do with your input data

Comment: We've solved the problem. Our server sends some "markers" in the message, the character '#' in the beggining and in the end.
I had to remove the markers before decrypting the message.
Since it's an old server, the lack of documentation was not helping me, so I didn't know that.
Thanks for your interest and yout help, @jzeferino and @Sven-Michael!! Stübe 
Btw, the input message was just an ineligible string : )